# Can't find the mistake I'm making in the proof of triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I've produced the following proof of the triangle inequality:

$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

$\iff \sqrt{(a+b)^2} \leq \sqrt{(a)^2} + \sqrt{(b)^2}$

$\iff (a+b)^2 \leq a^2 + 2\sqrt{(ab)^2}+b^2$ (we squared both sides)

$\iff a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \leq a^2 + 2\sqrt{(ab)^2}+b^2$ (just developping LHS)

$\iff ab \leq \sqrt{(ab)^2}$ (simplified expression)

$\iff (ab)^2 \leq (ab)^2$ (squared both sides)

Therefore, since the last statement is a tautology, using the transitivity of the logical biconditional, the statement at the beginning of the biconditional chain is also a tautology, proving the theorem.

I've been told there's a mistake in my proof, but I've been meditating on it for some time now and I have no clue where I've gone wrong. Would someone have any hints on the mistake I'm making?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Squaring both sides of an inequality does *not* produce an equivalent inequality.

Comment: The equivalence $ab\leq \sqrt{(ab)^2}\iff (ab)^2\leq (ab)^2$ does not hold unless $ab\geq 0$. Note that the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is not increasing over the negative numbers.

Comment: If your proof were correct then you would actually have shown that $|a+b| =|a|+|b|$ for all $a, b$, which is obviously wrong. So substitute (for example) $a=-1$ and $b=1$  everywhere and check where things go wrong.

Comment: thank you very much for the tips!

Comment: @MartinR unless the terms are positive!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real quantities, the true equivalence is $$X\le \sqrt Y\Leftrightarrow (X< 0\land Y\ge 0)\lor (X\ge 0\land X^2\le Y)$$ This comes into play when you assert that $$ab\le \sqrt{(ab)^2}\Leftrightarrow (ab)^2\le (ab)^2$$

instead of $$ab\le \sqrt{(ab)^2}\Leftrightarrow ab<0\lor ((ab)^2\le (ab)^2\land ab\ge 0)$$

This is of course a simple tautology, but a different one.

Comment: Thank you very much for spelling out the implication!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is another way to approach it:
\begin{align*}
|ab| \geq ab & \Longleftrightarrow 2|a||b| \geq 2ab\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |a|^{2} + 2|a||b| + |b|^{2} \geq a^{2} + 2ab + b^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (|a| + |b|)^{2} \geq (a+b)^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |a| + |b| \geq \sqrt{(a+b)^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |a| + |b| \geq |a + b|
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, this answer was just as helpful as the accepted one!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to show it ...

First note that:

1. $x\leq|x|$,
2. $-x\leq|x|$,
3. if $x\leq u$ and $y\leq v$ then $x+y\leq u+v$,
4. $|x|=\max(x,-x)$,
5. if $x\leq u$ and $y\leq u$ then $\max(x,y)\leq u$.

By 1 and 3 we have $a+b \leq |a|+|b|$. By 2 and 3 we have $-(a+b) = -a-b \leq |a|+|b|$. So finally, by 4 and 5 we get $|a+b|=\max(a+b,-(a+b)) \leq |a|+|b|.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!